# extend the web controls in c#

Tags: asp.net, menu

I am developing the menu webpart using the asp.net Menu control in user control page for sharepoint 2010. I want to make available properties and methods of menu to developer (API). SO i need to either override all the menu control members in custom class which extends Menu. but it is not abstract control right? so how i can do this? How i can make available to developers to extend the menu control ? is i need to write extension methods for menu control ? please guide. I am using VS 2010 with 3.5 framework.

Comment: is my question wrong ??? why -1 ?

Comment: Shame full for all globle programmers... no answer he he he...lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple google search emits [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/customhtmlattributes.aspx)